# Using `pidof` with `sh -c`

Tags: shell, process, pidof

I was wondering why this command line does not print `pidof sh`:

```
$ sh -c "var=`pidof sh` ; echo \$var; ps -H"
```

This one prints `123` as expected

```
$ sh -c "var=123 ; echo \$var; ps -H"
```

I am on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the quotes. One way to do it:

```
sh -c "var=\"`pidof sh`\" ; echo \$var; ps -H"
```

Another:

```
sh -c "var=\"\`pidof sh\`\" ; echo \$var; ps -H"
```

Notice that they differ in the moment when the `pidof sh` is executed! In the first version, the expression within backticks (`pidof sh`) is executed by your current shell - that is *before* `sh -c` is run. In the second, it is the `sh -c` command that executes `pidof`. More than that, the `pidof` is executed within a subshell that evaluates the expression within backticks - so you get one additional pid listed in the `var` variable. (Put it more simple: **the backticks invoke another shell** which is then listed by pidof.)

A better way for both would be to use `$( ... )` or `\$( ... )`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I don't understand what do you mean when you say "Notice that they differ in the moment when the pidof sh is executed!"

Comment: Also why do I get two pids listed on printing $var. I that for pidof program?

Comment: This is because at the time when `pidof` is executed, a second `sh` is running (a subshell) in order to evaluate what is between the backticks.

Comment: @abc I suspect you meant to write `sh -c 'var=$(pidof sh); echo $var; ps -H'`. With the double quotes, as rozcietrzewiacz said, the `pidof` command was executed to build the string that is passed to `sh`. With single quotes, the text between the quotes is passed to `sh` as is.